# Function name built from macro using pre-defined string and argument

Tags: c++, macros

I'm currently having a problem with the definition of a macro in C++.

I want it like this:

```
#define MY_MACRO (Name, Address) __int32 Get_Name() { return Address; }
```

Now, when I call it like this:

```
MY_MACRO(Test, 0x10);
```

it spits out

```
__int32 Get_Name() { return 0x10; }
            ^^^^
```

instead of

```
__int32 Get_Test() { return 0x10; }
            ^^^^
```

How can I solve this issue? I really need the `Get_` in the name, and then the name passed by the argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [macro concatenation operator](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp7a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fclrc09numnum.htm).

```
#define MY_MACRO (Name, Address) __int32 Get_##Name() { return Address; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to concatenate strings this way

```
#define MY_MACRO(Name, Address) __int32 Get_##Name() { return Address; }
```

Comment: The spaces padding `##` will cause issues in some compilers. That very well may parse as `Get_  Name`.